# Could not edit systemd service file

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2, systemd

Need to edit following entries:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```

in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file

---

```
$ sudo -E systemctl edit docker.service
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

did not update the service file after restart(`sudo systemctl restart docker.service`)

---

**Edit**

On AWS EC2, below is the issue:

```
$ nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

`/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` still shows unmodified

---

1) What is the recommended approach to edit service file(`docker.service`)?

2) Why `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` cannot be edited directly?

Comment: Remember that _anyone_ who can reach that TCP port will have unrestricted root-level access over your system, with no authentication or logging at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze docker daemon is TLS enabled

Comment: @jww can you migrate this question? I am not able to delted this question

Comment: @DavidMaze I think you are right... `0.0.0.0:2376` is making my docker daemon accessed by many users... not sure how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a systemd drop-in file for `docker.service`.

- Create `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` file with contents

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

- Reload systemd unit files.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

*NOTE: Reloading systemctl daemon is required after editing any systemd unit file that's as per systemd design. For more info check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400763/why-cant-systemd-reload-unit-files-automatically).*

- Restart docker daemon.

```
systemctl restart docker
```

You need to restart docker daemon to pick up the latest updated systemd unit file.

For more info check [this](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd).

Comment: When I say `sudo -E systemctl edit docker.service` the file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/.#override.conf70b855eba026867d` get created. Is this not a right file to edit?

Comment: Can you manually try to create the file and try these steps. Give it a try.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: If you don;t know the password. Can you try. `sudo sh` or `sudo bash` and then run the commands.

Comment: But that would be the hack... I cannot do this in production

Comment: I don't know any other possible workaround for that.

Comment: Changing `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` should also work. Please read the first para mentioned here https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html it will clear most of your doubts.

Comment: For anyone curious why `ExecStart=` was included twice in the override file, refer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468067).